# How to import a interface in delphi?

Tags: delphi, interface

I  want to get folder path from windows library (eg: Libraries\Documents ) . I find it need to use [IShellLibrary interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/windows/desktop/dd391719%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I can't find declared in `ShlObj` (Delphi 2009 x64 win7) . I wonder how to import this interface to my code ?
[image]

Comment: It is defined for the first time in XE2 Winapi.ShlObj.pas

Comment: Can it import in Delphi 2009 ? or how I use it in Delphi 2009 ? (it not defined in D2009 )

Comment: If you're willing to use use late binding, you don't have to declare it, just assign it to a Variant variable and call it's methods and properties. The great downside is you don't have any help from the compiler to check for misspelled calls.

Comment: @jachguate  It work failed  , I update a pic

Comment: as said, declare the variable as a Variant: `var psl: Variant;`

Comment: @jachguate Late binding is for automation interfaces. This is not one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you cannot use a modern Delphi which includes this interface, you need to translate the interface from the Windows header files, in this case `Shobjidl.h`. In Delphi it begins like this:

```
IShellLibrary = interface(IUnknown) 
  ['{11A66EFA-382E-451A-9234-1E0E12EF3085}']
  ....
end;
```

The GUID can be found in the header file. You then need to add in the functions. It's essential that you add them in the same order as they are declared in the header file. The functions should all be declared as `stdcall`.

I don't want to post the entire interface declaration from the XE3 source because I'd consider that to be a copyright violation.

Perhaps if you search hard enough you might find this code on the web somewhere. And in fact, I just found it: http://mustangpeakcommonlib.googlecode.com/svn-history/r12/trunk/Source/MPShellTypes.pas